# Select count of rows that have a certain number of rows in a related table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I'm not quite sure why this one is giving me so much trouble this morning. I'm going to chalk it up to being Friday morning. :)  The goal is to count, by frequency, the number of real estate properties in that period that have zero photos, three photos and six or more photos. I need a result set that looks like this (**NOTE: the "three column or more should NOT include ones that have exactly six -- there can be a max of six photos**):

```
Period Start      Period End        Zero      ThreeOrMore     ExactlySix
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/1/2011          1/7/2011          15        132             512
1/8/2011          1/14/2011         44        123             402
```

I made the dates up, the SQL I have actually produces the correct week start/end dates.

My "Property" table looks like this:

```
PropertyRecId    Other fields
-----------------------------
12345            <blah>
56789            <blah>
```

My "PropertyPhoto" table looks like this (only the necessary fields included):

```
PropertyPhotoId   PropertyRecId     CreatedOn
---------------------------------------------
1                 12345             3/1/2011
2                 12345             3/1/2011
etc...
```

I'm using the query below but I'm not beholden to it. I just need to accomplish the goal. Keep in mind that with my existing query, I don't have access to the "Propery" record in my top-level select. I tried dropping the queries down into the secondary select where PeriodStart and PeriodEnd are created, but that just caused different issues.

```
DECLARE @DateStart datetime
DECLARE @DateEnd datetime
SET @DateStart = '1/1/2011'
SET @DateEnd = '12/31/2011'

DECLARE @Frequency varchar(50)
SET @Frequency = 'month'

SELECT
PeriodStart,
PeriodEnd,
??? As Zero,
??? As ThreeOrMore,
??? As ExactlySix
FROM (
SELECT
PeriodStart = CASE @Frequency
WHEN 'day'     THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedOn))
WHEN 'week'    THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), CreatedOn)))
WHEN 'month'   THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH,   0, CreatedOn), 0)))
WHEN 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, CreatedOn), 0)))
WHEN 'year'    THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(YEAR,    DATEDIFF(YEAR,    0, CreatedOn), 0)))
END,
PeriodEnd   = CASE @Frequency
WHEN 'day'     THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedOn)))
WHEN 'week'    THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), CreatedOn))))
WHEN 'month'   THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH,   0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
WHEN 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
WHEN 'year'    THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR,    DATEDIFF(YEAR,    0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
END     
FROM Property P
WHERE CreatedOn BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
) s
GROUP BY
PeriodStart,
PeriodEnd
ORDER BY PeriodStart
```

Comment: You `SELECT` from `Property p` but what about `PropertyPhoto`?  How are you ever going to get any counts without joining to that table.

You will need to add a `LEFT JOIN` as some properties do not have any pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `over` function in your subquery to get this, and `case` statements in your outer select to add 'em up:

```
DECLARE @Frequency varchar(50)
SET @Frequency = 'month'

SELECT
    PeriodStart,
    PeriodEnd,
    SUM(case when s.PhotoCount = 0 then 1 else 0 end) As Zero,
    SUM(case when s.PhotoCount between 3 and 5 then 1 else 0 end) As ThreeOrMore,
    SUM(case when s.PhotoCount = 6 then 1 else 0 end) As ExactlySix
FROM (
    SELECT
        PeriodStart = 
        CASE @Frequency
            WHEN 'day'     THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedOn))
            WHEN 'week'    THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), CreatedOn)))
            WHEN 'month'   THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH,   0, CreatedOn), 0)))
            WHEN 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, CreatedOn), 0)))
            WHEN 'year'    THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(YEAR,    DATEDIFF(YEAR,    0, CreatedOn), 0)))
        END,
        PeriodEnd   = 
        CASE @Frequency
            WHEN 'day'     THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedOn)))
            WHEN 'week'    THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), CreatedOn))))
            WHEN 'month'   THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH,   0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
            WHEN 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
            WHEN 'year'    THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR,    DATEDIFF(YEAR,    0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
        END,
        p.PropertyRecId,
        COUNT(ph.PropertyPhotoId) over (partition by p.PropertyRecId) as PhotoCount
    FROM
        Property P
        left join PropertyPhoto ph on
            p.PropertyRecId = ph.PropertyRecId
    WHERE 
        CreatedOn BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
) s
GROUP BY
    PeriodStart,
    PeriodEnd
ORDER BY 
    PeriodStart
```

You can also make your inner query with a traditional `group by`, but I love me some `over` and wanted to bring it to your attention:

```
SELECT
    PeriodStart = 
    CASE @Frequency
        WHEN 'day'     THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedOn))
        WHEN 'week'    THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), CreatedOn)))
        WHEN 'month'   THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH,   0, CreatedOn), 0)))
        WHEN 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, CreatedOn), 0)))
        WHEN 'year'    THEN DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, DATEADD(YEAR,    DATEDIFF(YEAR,    0, CreatedOn), 0)))
    END,
    PeriodEnd   = 
    CASE @Frequency
        WHEN 'day'     THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(day, 1, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CreatedOn)))
        WHEN 'week'    THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, 7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, CreatedOn), CreatedOn))))
        WHEN 'month'   THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH,   DATEDIFF(MONTH,   0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
        WHEN 'quarter' THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(QUARTER, DATEDIFF(QUARTER, 0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
        WHEN 'year'    THEN DATEADD(s, -1, DATEADD(hour, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, -1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR,    DATEDIFF(YEAR,    0, CreatedOn) + 1, 0)))))
    END,
    p.PropertyRecId,
    COUNT(ph.PropertyPhotoId) over (partition by p.PropertyRecId) as PhotoCount
FROM
    Property P
    left join PropertyPhoto ph on
        p.PropertyRecId = ph.PropertyRecId
WHERE 
    CreatedOn BETWEEN @DateStart AND @DateEnd
GROUP BY
    p.PropertyRecId,
    p.CreatedOn
```

Comment: +1 you beat me to it..was typing a long one out too :( thanks a lot eric!

Comment: +1 The join on `property` might be superfluous, `PropertyRecId` is in the `PropertyPhoto` table too.  And `.PhotoCount > 3` should be `.PhotoCount in (3,4,5)`. per the question

Comment: @Adomar - Made it `between 3 and 5` because that's clearer, and it's quicker than `in`.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?:

```
--1 : Make a lookup-up table of period start/end
CREATE TABLE #PERIODS (
    [Period Start] datetime
  , [Period End]   datetime
);

DECLARE @firstDay datetime
DECLARE @rowid int
SET @firstDay = '2011-01-01'
WHILE @firstDay < '2012-01-01'
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #PERIODS VALUES ( @firstDay, DATEADD(DAY,6,@firstDay));
    SET @firstDay = @firstDay + 7
END
GO

-- 2 Count the photos per property per period
CREATE TABLE #PHOTOCOUNT (
    [Period Start] datetime
  , [Period End]   datetime
  , PropertyRecId  int
  , PhotoCount     int
);
GO

INSERT INTO #PHOTOCOUNT
SELECT 
    PD.[Period Start]
  , PD.[Period End]   
  , Property.PropertyRecId
  , COUNT(PropertyPhoto.PropertyPhotoId) AS PhotoCount
FROM 
    #PERIODS AS PD,
    Property
    LEFT JOIN PropertyPhoto
        ON Property.PropertyRecId = PropertyPhoto.PropertyRecId 
WHERE 
    PropertyPhoto.PropertyRecId Is Null
    OR PropertyPhoto.CreatedOn BETWEEN PD.[Period Start] AND PD.[Period End]
GROUP BY 
    PD.[Period Start]
  , PD.[Period End]   
  , Property.PropertyRecId;
GO

-- 3 Categorize by 0, 3 to 5, 6
SELECT 
    [Period Start]
  , [Period End]
  , SUM(RANGES.Zero) AS Zero
  , SUM(RANGES.ThreeToFive) AS ThreeToFive
  , SUM(RANGES.Six) AS Six
FROM (
    SELECT 
        [Period Start]
      , [Period End]
      , Zero = CASE WHEN PhotoCount = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
      , ThreeToFive = CASE WHEN PhotoCount BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
      , Six = CASE WHEN PhotoCount = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    FROM #PHOTOCOUNT
) RANGES
GROUP BY
    [Period Start]
  , [Period End] 
;

DROP TABLE #PERIODS;
DROP TABLE #PHOTOCOUNT;
```

Comment: This returns the number of photo's for a period.  The OP is looking for the number of properties with a number of photo's for a period.

Comment: No, it returns number of properties with number of photos. Scroll down to the last step.

Comment: @jmh_gr - This query is rather inefficient. Temp tables and a pointless subquery all add up. Just easier to do it in one query than to try to go through this whole shebang. You also drop `#PERIODS` just before you use it again. This method doesn't scale very well, and I'd advise against it.

Comment: @Eric - I think you misread the post; I dropped #PERIODS only at the very end. Regarding the "efficiency": Are you referring to disk usage? Memory usage? CPU usage? Materializing a temporary table is legitimate, it's a really fast loop that executes within milliseconds, and I think combining everything in one nested query vs. several discrete steps is a matter of balancing clarity vs. conciseness -- humans still have to read code.

Comment: @Eric: I would agree with jmh_gr here.  SQL Server executes most joins using a temporary table.  The fact that it's a named temporary table, as in this answer, doesn't make a difference in terms of performance or scalability.